# Cannot import new modules into venv project

Tags: python, virtualenv

This is my first time working with a virtual environment so I'm not sure I'm doing anything right. I've followed the setup guide in the "flask mega tutorial"

```
$ python3 -m venv flask
$ flask/bin/pip3 install flask
$ flask/bin/pip3 install flask-login
$ flask/bin/pip3 install flask-openid
$ flask/bin/pip3 install flask-mail
$ flask/bin/pip3 install flask-sqlalchemy
$ flask/bin/pip3 install sqlalchemy-migrate
$ flask/bin/pip3 install flask-whooshalchemy
$ flask/bin/pip3 install flask-wtf
$ flask/bin/pip3 install flask-babel
$ flask/bin/pip3 install guess_language
$ flask/bin/pip3 install flipflop
$ flask/bin/pip3 install coverage
```

And everything worked fine. Until I realized I needed a new package (two of them actually, yaml and requests) I installed them like I normally would, outside of the virtual environment, with `pip3 install packagename`

I can import the packages in any other python file, I can import them in the ipython3 shell, but I cannot import them in my flask project. If I place them in views.py and then execute `./run.py`

I get the error

```
ImportError: No module named 'yaml'
```

I've tried installing them again with `apt-get` but nothing changes.

my flask files are as follows:

run.py

```
#!flask/bin/python3
from app import app
app.run(debug=True)
```

__ init __.py

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('config')

from app import views
```

veiws.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, session, redirect, url_for
from app import app
import time, os, subprocess
import yaml

## other stuff that works until I try to import yaml or any new package
```

Comment: install `yaml` and `requests` inside your virtualenv like you do wtih the flask packages

Comment: As @J.R. said you have to make sure they packages install inside of the venv. IMO it's easiest if you just activate the venv  "$source venv/bin/activate"  assuming that venv is your virtual environment's name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not able to import the modules since they are not installed in the virtualenv `flask` that you created. Solve this by installing it in the same way as the other `flask` modules, ie. following your approach:

```
$ python3 -m venv flask
$ flask/bin/pip3 install flask
$ flask/bin/pip3 install flask-login
$ flask/bin/pip3 install flask-openid
$ flask/bin/pip3 install flask-mail
$ flask/bin/pip3 install flask-sqlalchemy
$ flask/bin/pip3 install sqlalchemy-migrate
$ flask/bin/pip3 install flask-whooshalchemy
$ flask/bin/pip3 install flask-wtf
$ flask/bin/pip3 install flask-babel
$ flask/bin/pip3 install guess_language
$ flask/bin/pip3 install flipflop
$ flask/bin/pip3 install coverage
$ flask/bin/pip3 install yaml
$ flask/bin/pip3 install requests
```

Comment: This fixes it! I still don't understand why the venv isn't able to access these particular global packages even though it is fine with other ones, do you happen to have any insight on that?

Comment: What packages are you refering to? Btw. you can use the system site-flag to inherit packages from your global repository, eg. `virtualenv --system-site-packages flask`.